# Firebase Timestamp to DateTime with default value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a Firebase Timestamp to a DateTime to display in a text widget. This is all wrapped in a Streambuilder. The problem is that when I'm querying the data i don't know if there has been set a timestamp yet.

I have tried to try and catch multiple conversions but I always get an exception when I try to display the data.

```
startingString = DateFormat('kk:mm').format(snapshot.data['startingTime'].toDate());
```

this works fine if there is a timestamp in firebase but it fails if there is none.

Many thanks to everyone who can help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be a casting problem. Try this:

```dart
final timeStamp = snapshot.data['startingTime'] as TimeStamp;
var startingString = '--';
if (timeStamp == null) {
  // null case
} else {
  startingString = DateFormat('kk:mm').format(timeStamp.toDate());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked!! I implemented it using ternary operator inline in text widget

Answer (score 0):

try to add a field of type string and assign it a value of DateTime.now();

and then try to parse it using

```dart
var myTime = await DateTime.parse(snapshot.data['time']);
```

then format it.